# javascript / angularjs post response headers before redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, post

my server gets a POST request then automatically redirects (Status Code 302) to a GET request with parameters.
I need to get the Response headers of the POST request.
What actually happens is that i get the Response headers of the GET.
I am using angularjs $resource, but a solution for native javascript will also be appreciated. Thanks!